# Is it correct to ask " What degrees is it outside?"

Tags: grammaticality, questions

My friend keeps saying that asking "What degrees is it outside?" is not correct, is she right?

Comment: The smallest modification to your sentence that would be regarded as standard would be `What, in degrees, is it outside?`.

Comment: Hugh, you'd really need one more modification, "What temperature, in degrees, is it outside?" otherwise the sentence is still (slightly) ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your friend is right. You can't say "What degrees is it outside?". What you can say is:

> How many degrees is it outside?
>
> What's the temperature outside?

Answer (score 2):

**No,** **it isn't correct to ask "What degrees is it outside?".**

You have several options to find out what temperature is.

> - You know the temperature outside? (coloquial)
> - What's the temperature outside?
> - If it is very cold: "How cold is it outside?"
> - If it is very hot: "How hot is it outside?

In the last two examples, even though you're not asking what temperature is, the answer will probably be: "...somelhting around the low thirties."  "around freezing"  "below freezing", "in the three digits"  (considering the Farenheit Scale)